# How to open epubs in Chrome by link

Tags: google-chrome, iis, https, webdav, epub

I have a https:// (The server is a webdav server on IIS) link to an epub. Now I would like to open it in Chrome with the ePUB Reader Extention automatically by clicking on it. It works fine for PDFs but not for epubs. I do get an ERROR 404.  But wenn I download the link with carotdav, I can get the epub file. SO THE LINK is valid.

Edit: IF I RENAME the file to Extention .RAR it I can download it with wget. But with Extention EPUB or EPU I also can not download it with wget.

How to proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. in IIS on WINDOWS 10 Server there was the MIME-type missing. I had to define in MIMETYPEs the .epub as `application/epub+zip`. Now I can download and use the ePub Reader for Chrome [Here_to_download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epubreader/jhhclmfgfllimlhabjkgkeebkbiadflb/related?hl=en) to open the ePub in Chrome.